# Find $P(A \cap B)$ with $P(A)=0.4$, $P(B) = 0.3$ and $P(A \cup B) = 0.6$

Tags: probability

> Find $P(A \cap B)$ with $P(A)=0.4$, $P(B) = 0.3$  and $P(A \cup B) =
>  0.6$.

My professor doesn't specify whether these events are mutually exclusive. If I solve this as if they are, I get
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)*P(B) = 0.12$$

If I solve this as if they are not, I get

$$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B) \\
\Leftrightarrow 0.6 = 0.4+0.3 -P(A\cap B)\Leftrightarrow \\
0.6 -0.4-0.3 = -P(A \cap B) \Leftrightarrow \\
0.1 = P(A\cap B)$$

The values are close, kind of. My professor solved this as if they are not mutually exclusive. Is there a way of telling, or did he simply forget to mention that?

Comment: if they were mutually exclusive, then we'd have $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$, and we don't in this case

Comment: A reminder, if $A$ and $B$ are *mutually exclusive* events will imply that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$, and for most events this is not true.  *Independent* events will imply that $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$, and for most events this is not true.  Do not confuse the terms mutually exclusive with independent.  They mean very different things, and the formulas that you get to use for their respective cases may *not* be used for arbitrary cases where you are unsure of whether they are in fact mutually exclusive or independent respectively.

Comment: If you are ever unsure on whether or not some events are independent or not, then you should always assume they are not and be pleasantly surprised in the event that the numbers show you that they are... but until such time as you have *proven* to yourself that they are you may not use $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $A$ and $ B$ are [mutually exclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity#Probability), $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

In this case, that would mean $0.6=0.4+0.3$, which is clearly not so.

Answer (score 1):

J.W. Tanner is exactly right. In the case that A and B were mutually exclusive, both can not happen at the same time so   $P(A∩B)$ would just be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the general formula which is true in all cases. Where $A$ and $B$ are events, we have $$P(A\cup B)= P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$ This formula is true regardless of whether or not the events are mutually exclusive (and more generally, regardless of whether or not they are independent).

By definition, if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then $P(A\cap B)=0$. Therefore, in the mutually exclusive case, we must have $P(A\cup B)= P(A)+P(B)$. As noted by previous answers, this is not the case here. This is why your professor was able to proceed as if $A$ and $B$ were not mutually exclusive.