# Find $P(\lnot A| B)$ with $P(A)=0.4$, $P(B)=0.3$ and $P(A\cup B)=0.6$

Tags: probability

I did:

$$P(\lnot A| B) = \frac{P(\lnot A \cap B)}{P(B)} \\
P(\lnot A \cap B) = P(\lnot A)*P(B) \\
P(\lnot A) = 1-P(A)$$

So,

$$P(\lnot A ) = 1-0.4 = 0.6 \\
P(\lnot A \cap B) = 0.6*0.3 = 0.18 \\
P(\lnot A |B) = \frac{0.18}{0.3} = 0.6$$

In the solutions it's $2/3$. What went wrong?

Comment: You went from $P(\neg A\cap B)$ to $P(\neg A)\cdot P(B)$.  What gave you the idea that this was allowed?

Comment: The equality $P(\lnot A \cap B) = P(\lnot A)*P(B)$ is not justified.

Comment: @JMoravitz Isn't the formula $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$?

Comment: It is, however $P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)\cdot P(B)$ in most circumstances.  You should have heard this already in a [recent question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538176/find-pa-cap-b-with-pa-0-4-pb-0-3-and-pa-cup-b-0-6?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A\cap B)$ is equal to $P(A)\cdot P(B)$ if **and only if** $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  The problem here has not told us that $A$ and $B$ are independent (*nor has it suggested that $\neg A$ and $B$ are independent*) so your second line is incorrect.

---

Instead, recognize that $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ in order to calculate $P(A\cap B)$.

From here, recognize that $P(B) = P(A\cap B)+P(\neg A\cap B)$ in order to calculate $P(\neg A\cap B)$.  Then continue.

Comment: But how do I find $P(\lnot A \cap B)$?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire what is unclear about my hints?  I'll color what is known in blue... $\color{blue}{P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)}-P(A\cap B)$.... so from here, we can now calculate $P(A\cap B)$ since everything else there is known... so it has joined our collection of knowns so from here out we can also color that blue since we know its value.  Then on the next line, we have $\color{blue}{P(B)=P(A\cap B)}+P(\neg A\cap B)$... we have enough information to calculate $P(\neg A\cap B)$ now, yes?

Comment: Sorry I misread your post. I had already calculated $P(A\cap B) = 0.1$ in a previous exercise. How do you know that $P(B) = P(A \cap B) + P(\lnot A \cap B)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability or alternately phrased, as an event or as a set you have that $B = B\cap \Omega = B\cap (A\cup \neg A) = (B\cap A)\cup (B\cap \neg A)$ and these two parenthetical expressions at the end are themselves mutually exclusive events